# Spring integration reply message hangs until the 'timing out TcpNioConnection' occurs

Tags: spring-integration

i want to use spring integration for TCP communication with another server (written in C language).

Exchange data between servers are raw bytes, but messages have no delimiter.

Therefore i've written my own Serializer/Deserializer that extends **AbstractByteArraySerializer**.

But, when i send message over MessagingGateway -> TcpOutboundGateway -> TcpNioClientConnectionFactory, reply message hangs until the timing out TcpNioConnection occurs.

Here is my SI java configuration :

```
@Bean(name = "loggingChannel")
public MessageChannel loggingChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@GlobalChannelInterceptor()
public ChannelInterceptor wiretap() {
    return new WireTap(loggingChannel(), s -> true);
}

private int port = 10101;

private String host = "10.1.3.119";

@Bean
public MessageChannel toTcp() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel fromTcp() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Autowired
public PerunGateway perunGateway;

@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "toTcp", defaultReplyChannel = "fromTcp")
public interface PerunGateway {

    @Gateway
    byte[] sendCommand(byte[] message);
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toTcp")
public TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutGate() {
    TcpOutboundGateway gate = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    gate.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory());
    gate.setOutputChannelName("fromTcp");
    gate.setRequestTimeout(5000);
    return gate;
}

@Bean
public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory() {
    TcpNioClientConnectionFactory tnccf = new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
    tnccf.setSoTimeout(1000);
    tnccf.setSingleUse(true);
    tnccf.setSerializer(new SunByteArrayRawSerializer());
    tnccf.setDeserializer(new SunByteArrayRawSerializer());
    return tnccf;
}
```

And output i get after sending the message :

```
2015-11-12 13:49:09.032 DEBUG 10329 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'toTcp', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[150], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@66e6fc48, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@66e6fc48, id=e5425395-e1cb-8cc7-20fd-eb5b9be3a615, timestamp=1447332549031}]
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.032 DEBUG 10329 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'loggingChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[150], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@66e6fc48, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@66e6fc48, id=e5425395-e1cb-8cc7-20fd-eb5b9be3a615, timestamp=1447332549031}]
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.033 DEBUG 10329 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler#0 received message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[150], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@66e6fc48, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@66e6fc48, id=e5425395-e1cb-8cc7-20fd-eb5b9be3a615, timestamp=1447332549031}]
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.033  INFO 10329 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=byte[150], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@66e6fc48, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@66e6fc48, id=e5425395-e1cb-8cc7-20fd-eb5b9be3a615, timestamp=1447332549031}]
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.034 DEBUG 10329 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'loggingChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[150], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@66e6fc48, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@66e6fc48, id=e5425395-e1cb-8cc7-20fd-eb5b9be3a615, timestamp=1447332549031}]
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.034 DEBUG 10329 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway          : tcpOutGate received message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[150], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@66e6fc48, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@66e6fc48, id=e5425395-e1cb-8cc7-20fd-eb5b9be3a615, timestamp=1447332549031}]
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.034 DEBUG 10329 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory : Opening new socket connection to 10.1.3.119:10101
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.042 DEBUG 10329 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection  : New connection 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.043 DEBUG 10329 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory : clientConnectionFactory: Added new connection: 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.045 TRACE 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory : clientConnectionFactory: Connection is open: 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.045 TRACE 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory : Host 10.1.3.119 port 10101 SelectionCount: 0
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.048 DEBUG 10329 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway          : Added pending reply 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.049 DEBUG 10329 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection  : 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19 writing 150
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.049 DEBUG 10329 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection  : 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19 Message sent GenericMessage [payload=byte[150], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@66e6fc48, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@66e6fc48, id=e5425395-e1cb-8cc7-20fd-eb5b9be3a615, timestamp=1447332549031}]
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.111 TRACE 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory : clientConnectionFactory: Connection is open: 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.111 TRACE 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory : Host 10.1.3.119 port 10101 SelectionCount: 1
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.114 DEBUG 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection  : 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19 Reading...
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.115 DEBUG 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection  : 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19 Running an assembler
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.115 TRACE 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection  : Before read:0/61440
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.115 TRACE 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-3] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection  : 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19 Nio message assembler running...
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.115 TRACE 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-3] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection  : 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19 checking data avail: 0 pending: true
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.116 TRACE 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-3] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection  : 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19 checking data avail (convert): 0 pending: true
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.116 TRACE 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection  : After read:102/61440
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.116 TRACE 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection  : After flip:0/102
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.116 DEBUG 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection  : Read 102 into raw buffer
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.116 TRACE 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection  : 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19 Sending 102 to pipe
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.116 TRACE 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory : clientConnectionFactory: Connection is open: 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19
        2015-11-12 13:49:09.117 TRACE 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory : Host 10.1.3.119 port 10101 SelectionCount: 0
        2015-11-12 13:49:10.117  WARN 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory : Timing out TcpNioConnection 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19
        2015-11-12 13:49:10.118 DEBUG 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory : clientConnectionFactory: Removed closed connection: 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19
        2015-11-12 13:49:10.119 TRACE 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory : Host 10.1.3.119 port 10101 SelectionCount: 0
        2015-11-12 13:49:11.117 TRACE 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-3] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection  : 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19 checking data avail: 0 pending: false
        2015-11-12 13:49:11.117 TRACE 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-3] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway          : onMessage: 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19(GenericMessage [payload=byte[108], headers={ip_address=10.1.3.119, id=1006fc9a-8be4-3722-3cbb-9250714b47ec, ip_hostname=10.1.3.119, ip_tcp_remotePort=10101, ip_connectionId=10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19, timestamp=1447332551117}])
        2015-11-12 13:49:11.117 TRACE 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-3] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection  : 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19 checking data avail: 0 pending: false
        2015-11-12 13:49:11.118 TRACE 10329 --- [pool-1-thread-3] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection  : 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19 Nio message assembler exiting... avail: 0
        2015-11-12 13:49:11.118 DEBUG 10329 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway          : Response GenericMessage [payload=byte[108], headers={ip_address=10.1.3.119, id=1006fc9a-8be4-3722-3cbb-9250714b47ec, ip_hostname=10.1.3.119, ip_tcp_remotePort=10101, ip_connectionId=10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19, timestamp=1447332551117}]
        2015-11-12 13:49:11.118 DEBUG 10329 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway          : Removed pending reply 10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19
```

Any ideas whats going on ?

Here is my custom deserialize method :

```
@Override
public byte[] deserialize(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Available to read:" + inputStream.available());
    }

    byte[] header = new byte[2];
    header[0] = (byte) inputStream.read();
    if (header[0] < 0) {
        throw new SoftEndOfStreamException("Stream closed between payloads");
    }

    header[1] = (byte) inputStream.read();
    if (header[1] < 0) {
        throw new SoftEndOfStreamException("Stream closed between payloads");
    }

    int val = getIntFromTwoBytes(header);

    byte[] length = new byte[val];
    for (int i = 0; i < val; i++) {
        length[i] = (byte) inputStream.read();
    }

    int messageLength;
    if (val == 2) {
        messageLength = getIntFromTwoBytes(length);
    } else if (val == 4) {
        messageLength = getIntFromFourBytes(length);
    } else throw new IOException("Unexpected count of bytes that holds message length");

    byte[] answer = new byte[messageLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < messageLength; i++) {
        int bite = inputStream.read();
        if (bite < 0) {
            throw new SoftEndOfStreamException("Stream closed between payloads");
        }
        answer[i] = (byte) bite;
    }

    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(2 + val + messageLength);
    b.put(header);
    b.put(length);
    b.put(answer);
    return b.array();
}
```

We use own binary protocol, so i know exact length of incoming message.

Comment: I don't see a timeout; I see the reply arriving:  `2015-11-12 13:49:11.118 DEBUG 10329 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway          : Response GenericMessage [payload=byte[108], headers={ip_address=10.1.3.119, id=1006fc9a-8be4-3722-3cbb-9250714b47ec, ip_hostname=10.1.3.119, ip_tcp_remotePort=10101, ip_connectionId=10.1.3.119:10101:38308:430e8a01-3d8a-462a-85a7-00ff6ce70b19, timestamp=1447332551117}]`

Comment: Sorry my bad. Question supposed to be  'Are the reply messages deliver back to the caller after Timing out TcpNioConnection ??'. Log says that reply data  was read into raw buffer at 13:49:09.116 , but 'onMessage' method was invoked 13:49:11.117 .... 2s 1ms later. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I see; sorry; missed this `2015-11-12 13:49:10.117  WARN`. It's not designed to do that, but it depends on how your deserializer is written. I'd need to see its code (or at least the error handling). You really need some way to delimit messages on the stream. The standard raw deserializer uses the peer closing the socket as the notification of end of message.

Comment: I added deserialize method to topic.

Answer (score 0):

That certainly wasn't the intent, but I see that, yes, the timeout is reported to the deserializer as a normal EOF rather than an IOException.

Our standard raw deserializer (that expects a socket close to end the stream) exhibits this problem...

```
if (bite < 0) {
    if (n == 0) {
        throw new SoftEndOfStreamException("Stream closed between payloads");
    }
    break;
}
```

In that the timeout is treated as an EOF and a partial message is returned (as a result of the break).

Your deserializer does not check if it has a partial result at all when it gets an EOF...

```
if (bite < 0) {
    throw new SoftEndOfStreamException("Stream closed between payloads");
}
```

...so I don't see how your deserializer can exhibit the problem. When we timeout the message, your deserializer should get the `-1`, which should simply cause the partial message to be dropped.

We need to change the NIO connection so the deserializer gets a timeout exception after a timeout, but your deserializer should not result in a partial message in this case.

I'll see if I can mock up some data to work with your code and get back to you.

**EDIT**

I am not seeing the behavior with your deserializer, only with our standard `ByteArrayRawDeserializer`.

I first tested with yours as supplied; then I polished it up a little - you should not be throwing `SoftEndOfStreamException` after you start decoding the data; that should be a hard IOException (e.g. by calling `checkClosure()`).

Here is my polished version:

```
@Override
public byte[] deserialize(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Available to read:" + inputStream.available());
    }

    byte[] header = new byte[2];
    header[0] = (byte) inputStream.read();
    if (header[0] < 0) {
        throw new SoftEndOfStreamException("Stream closed between payloads");
    }

    header[1] = (byte) inputStream.read();
    if (header[1] < 0) {
        checkClosure(-1);
    }

    ByteBuffer headerBB = ByteBuffer.wrap(header);
    int val = headerBB.getShort();

    byte[] length = new byte[val];
    for (int i = 0; i < val; i++) {
        length[i] = (byte) inputStream.read();
    }

    headerBB = ByteBuffer.wrap(length);
    int messageLength;
    if (val == 2) {
        messageLength = headerBB.getShort();
    }
    else if (val == 4) {
        messageLength = headerBB.getInt();
    }
    else {
        throw new IOException("Unexpected count of bytes that holds message length");
    }

    byte[] answer = new byte[messageLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < messageLength; i++) {
        int bite = inputStream.read();
        if (bite < 0) {
            checkClosure(-1);
        }
        answer[i] = (byte) bite;
    }

    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(2 + val + messageLength);
    b.put(header);
    b.put(length);
    b.put(answer);
    return b.array();
}
```

Comment: Edit; I can't reproduce it with your deserializer; only with ours; see the edit.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i see your point.  So when you used my deserializer, is the reply message  sent back to the caller immediately? Not after timing out connection as in my case ??

Comment: If the message is complete, yes; if it's a short message (still waiting for data) and it times out then, no, a message is not returned to the called. When I sent `"\u0000\u0002\u0000\u0005reply"` the reply is received. When I send  `"\u0000\u0002\u0000\u0005repl"`, nothing is received - even after the timeout.

Comment: Here's [the fix for our raw deserializer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/1629); I included a test for your code but it does not need any code changes to pass.

Comment: Thanks Garry for your quick responses. You have been right. You cannot reproduce timeout with my deserializer because it works as supposed to.  I dont know why was that happening yesterday, but it works now. Anyway i am glad you improved `ByteArrayRawDeserializer` thanks to this issue.